# How do I flip an image in memory?

Tags: c#, image, xna, flip, texture2d

I would like to flip an image and create a new Texture2D of that flipped image.

I have done some research and found that this code will create a new Texture2D;

```
RenderTarget2D newTarget = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, partWidth, partHeight)

GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(newTarget);

SpriteBatch.Draw(original, Vector2.Zero, partSourceRectangle, ... )

GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

Texture2D newTexture = (Texture2D)newTarget;
```

I understand that the newTexture is susceptible to being removed from memory so I am advised that I need to use getData/SetData to create a more permanent texture. Could anyone advise me on the specific syntax to do this?

Comment: Could you go into detail as to why you need to flip it in memory?  Why would a texture transform not be enough?  I understand that you might have a reason, but if you don't need to flip it in memory, you could save yourself a lot of cycles.

Comment: a texture transform would be great as long as the result is a new texture

Comment: Ok, this looks like it's a piece of XNA code?  Is that correct or is this in another API?

Comment: yes it's XNA code. C#

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it looks like one of the overloads for `SpriteBatch.Draw()` takes a scale.  If you want to flip the texture end for end (mirror) then you could try passing a `-1` for the scale value.  If you want to rotate it, then pass a rotation value to the function instead [SpriteBatch.Draw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx)

Comment: Also, do you absolutely need a new texture?  If you aren't going to do any other processing, couldn't you just use the `SpriteBatch.Draw()` that eventually gets you the texture that you want in place of wherever you would use that new generated texture?

Comment: ok that sounds great. in addition to that i would like to know how to copy the Texture2D data so it doesn't get removed from memory. could you advise me on the exact syntax for doing that?

Comment: what i am trying to do is a galaga clone. the enemies fly along a path (which is a list in memory) each node of the list contains a step count, a direction and a texture. i am loading in a sprite sheet with the enemies rotated 90 degrees over 7 frames. to simulate a full 360 degrees i need to flip the images both vertically and horizontally and create new textures so that i can populate the path list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next method saves flipped texture to new texture2D:

```
    public Texture2D SaveAsFlippedTexture2D(Texture2D input, bool vertical, bool horizontal)
    {
        Texture2D flipped = new Texture2D(input.GraphicsDevice, input.Width, input.Height);
        Color[] data = new Color[input.Width * input.Height];
        Color[] flipped_data = new Color[data.Length];

        input.GetData<Color>(data);

        for (int x = 0; x < input.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < input.Height; y++)
            {
                int index = 0;
                if (horizontal && vertical)
                    index = input.Width - 1 - x + (input.Height - 1 - y) * input.Width;
                else if (horizontal && !vertical)
                    index = input.Width - 1 - x + y * input.Width;
                else if (!horizontal && vertical)
                    index = x + (input.Height - 1 - y) * input.Width;
                else if (!horizontal && !vertical)
                    index = x + y * input.Width;

                flipped_data[x + y * input.Width] = data[index];
            }
        }

        flipped.SetData<Color>(flipped_data);

        return flipped;
    }
```

Example:
Load our texture then use the method, pass our texture as parameter to return new flipped texture to another texture. You can load your content inside game Update() method as well.

```
    Texture2D texture;
    Texture2D flippedTextureHorizontal;
    Texture2D flippedTextureVertical;
    Texture2D flippedTextureVerticalHorizontal;
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("kitty-cat");
        flippedTextureHorizontal = SaveAsFlippedTexture2D(texture, false, true);
        flippedTextureVertical = SaveAsFlippedTexture2D(texture, true, false);
        flippedTextureVerticalHorizontal = SaveAsFlippedTexture2D(texture, true, true);
    }
```

Draw method:

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearWrap, DepthStencilState.None, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        spriteBatch.Draw(flippedTextureHorizontal, new Vector2(texture.Width + offset, 0), null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        spriteBatch.Draw(flippedTextureVertical, new Vector2(texture.Width * 2 + offset * 2, 0), null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        spriteBatch.Draw(flippedTextureVerticalHorizontal, new Vector2(texture.Width * 3 + offset * 3, 0), null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Ouput:
[image: Output]

The alghorithm can be found [Here](http://stuckinprogramming.blogspot.ru/2011/01/how-to-flip-texture2d-vertically-or.html) as well.
The same result as above can be achieved by using code below for horizontal and vertical flipping at the same time:
But not sure it will be 100% correct

```
test = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, texture.Width, texture.Height);
int size = texture.Width * texture.Height;
Color[] data = new Color[size];
texture.GetData<Color>(data);
Array.Reverse(data, texture.Width, size - texture.Width);
test.SetData<Color>(data);
```